# Carrierwave with Uploadify giving undefined method `has_key?' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, uploadify, carrierwave

Rails 3.1, ActiveRecord, JQuery

I am using Carrierwave to upload an image to a model using AWS S3.  Very simple just one image per model. I want to use Uploadify with it.

It works fine without Uploadify, but with it I get the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `has_key?' for #<ImageUploader:0x00000103c7f2f0>):
```

The code for the uploader works on its own and I've followed [this post](http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder) to try to get Uploadify to work.  And then I used [this code](https://github.com/bhoggard/uploadtester31/blob/master/app/views/galleries/_image_list.html.haml) to get the CSRF issue taken care of.

The code to set up Uploadify in the edit.html.erb is:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject' %>
<% end %>
<%= content_for :scripts do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <% session_key_name = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>
    jQuery('input#facility_image').uploadify({
      'uploader'     : '/assets/uploadify.swf',
      'script'       : '<%=facilities_path%>',
      'fileDataName' : 'facility[image]',
      'fileExt'      : '*.png;*.jpg;*.gif',
      'cancelImg'    : '/assets/cancel.png',
      'multi'        : false,
      'scriptData'   :  {
           '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
           '<%= session_key_name %>' : encodeURIComponent('<%= u cookies[session_key_name] %>'),
           'authenticity_token': encodeURIComponent('<%= u form_authenticity_token %>'),
        },
      'auto'         : true,
      'buttonText'   : 'Upload Image',
      'onComplete'   : function(e, id, obj, response, data) {
        $('#images').append(response);
      }
    });
  </script>
<% end%>
```

Anyone know why this error is happening and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using devise, this is a better fix http://ariejan.net/2011/03/27/rails-3-devise-uploadify-no-flash-session-hacks